# Django: how to add csrf token when prepending a from using ajax

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms, ajaxform

I am adding a comment functionality in my project. And I am using ajax to make it dynamic so that when the user clicks on the comment submit button it will be added in the comment section dynamically without refreshing the page. But the problem is when prepending a form using ajax I cant add csrf token like this

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

in the form because ajax wouldn't understand it and take it as text.

```
function getids(postid){
console.log(postid)
$(postformid).one('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(event)
      console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
      create_comment(posted);
    });
}

// AJAX for posting
function create_comment(postid) {
    console.log("create comment is working!") // sanity check
    console.log(postid)
    console.log(talkid)
    $.ajax({
        url : "create_comment/"+postid, // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { the_comment : $(cmtext).val() }, // data sent with the post request

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            $(cmtext).val(''); // remove the value from the input
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            $(talkid).prepend(
              "<div class='col-1 p-0'><form' id=upvote' method='POST'>{%"csrf_token"%}<button 
              class='btn btn-md btn-outline-danger btn- 
              block p-auto' id='btnid' onclick='---' type='submit'></button></form></div>");
              console.log("success"); // sanity check
        },

    // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        }
    });
};
```

pretending my form here

```
<div class="row m-0" id="talk{{post.id}}"></div>
```

is there any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

just before the form tag inside your template.